# How do you call a from partial from different model in a layout/header

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails how do I call a form from another model in any given layout?  I have a login form I want to put in the header of every page.  I created a partial with the following in it:

```
<% form_for(@user_session) do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username, :class=>'' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>

    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me %><br />
  <br />

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Login' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

then tried calling that partial in my header and that doesn't seem to work.

```
<%= render :partial => 'user_sessions/login' %>
```

I get a "Called id for nil" error

Comment: Can you tell us the path of this login form located in `views`?

Comment: /views/user_sessions/_login.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from jmesserer over at railsforum, just needed to change:

```
<% form_for(@user_session) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<% form_for UserSession.new do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= render :partial=> 'user_sessions/login' :layout => false%>
```

Use this

I think you save your partial with '_login.rhtml' like ?

Comment: @sachinrathore11: True if he has included a layout which checks for existence of a logged in user! Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `<%= render @user_session %>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `@user_session` variable set up within all of your controller actions?

Comment: I belive so... I'm following the http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example, what I want to do is have a login form in the header of each page if the user is not logged in.